# Вывод текста: использовать echo или нет?

Tags: php, оптимизация, html

При создании любого сайта обязательно используется HTML код, для построения блоков и вообще построения сайта.

И часто этот код находиться в PHP-файле, так как нет смысла его выносить в отдельный файл, а потом еще инклудить.

Допустим, есть такой PHP файл и в нем есть такой код:

```
<?php

$title='Title';
$content='Content//';

echo <<<HTML
<div class='title'>$title</div>
<div class='content'>$content</div>
HTML;
```

Но его можно вывести еще так

```
<?php
    $title='Title';
    $content='Content//';
?>

<div class='title'><?echo $title; ?></div>
<div class='content'><?echo $content; ?></div>
```

Какой способ лучше использовать? Наверное, второй способ должен быть быстрее, но намного ли? Или всё же можно не думать о этом и писать как удобней?

А что, если через echo выводить много HTML кода?

Comment: Для вывода большого количества хтмл кода лучше использовать второй вариант. При большим объёмах производительность будет очень заметна.

Comment: @terantul а почему не использовать второй способ всегда?

Comment: Можете использовать всегда. Это Ваше право.)

Comment: @terantul там понятно что мое) Мне интересует что лучше)

Comment: Лично мне больше по-нраву вариант с шаблонизаторами, к примеру Smarty. Читабельность превосходная, отделение представления и скорость нормальная из-за кэширования шаблонов.

Comment: М11 интересовал вопрос оптимизации производительности, к сожалению Смарти этим похвастаться не может. М11 - используйте второй вариант, по производительности он лучше.

Comment: @uzumaxy не хотелось бы подключать какие-то библиотеки.

Comment: Вообще лучше использовать шаблоны с кешированием ;)

Comment: я б предложил twig

Comment: Хотите взгляд "со стороны"? От программиста, который никогда не писал web-странички.

--

Для меня первый вариант симпатичней (видимо привычней, очень похож на встроенный документ в shell). Т.е. он сходу более понятен, совершенно очевидно, что именно программа делает.

Тем более, как выяснилось из ответа @VenZell, он еще и быстрее (довольно понятно, почему). Уверен, что и памяти ему нужно меньше.

Comment: Чистый Smarty / Twig отработает в 3-4 раза медленнее echo. Но, думаю, при формировании страницы львиную долю времени занимают сложные вычисления, взаимодействие с хранилищем данных и прочие сложные операции. Вряд ли в каких-либо серьезных высоконагруженных проектах стоит вообще задумываться про "оптимизацию" путем использования echo-style при формировании станицы. Серьезного выигрыша мы не получим, а код значительно раздуется и усложниться в читабельности.

Comment: avp, на этом примере может и действительно симпатично выглядит подобный подход, но в реальных проектах код превращается в кровавое месиво. При таком походе невозможно наследование шаблонов, создание блоков, логика полностью мешается с представлением.

Comment: в любых проектах более 1-2 страниц echo-style сделает обновление дизайна очень сложным, по поводу производительности -- кеширование для этого и сделано, не? ;) И что считать высоконагруженным проектом?

вообще комменты типа echo это круто и надо его использовать потому что быстрее -- это ооочень плохо! ПОТОМ поддержка кода станен практически невозможной, да и лучше подумать над правильной архитектурой и реализовать на шаблонах, чем ковырять многокилометровые листинги, что бы закрыть какойлибо тег...

Comment: @uzumaxy, охотно верю. Тем более, что ПХП (мягко говоря) вообще не очень структурированный язык.

Насколько помню, изначально это был Personal Home Pages. Т.е. нечто маленькое, простенькое, для программирования "на коленке". 

Но, так уж сложилось..., а родовые болячки, надо понимать, и теперь дают себя знать.

--

@terantul, а что, "высоконагруженные проекты" (кстати, в **числах** Вы это как оцениваете?) тоже на ПХП пишут?

Comment: Пишут, умудряются связывать с СУБД MySQL и даже строить [мануалы][1]... С++ и CGI нынче не модно :( 


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/106311/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Тест будет красноречивее любых споров по поводу производительности:

```
<?php
$title='Title';
$content='Content//';

$start_a = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i<30000; ++$i) {
echo <<<HTML
<div class='title'>$title</div>
<div class='content'>$content</div>
HTML;
}
echo microtime(true) - $start_a;
?>
```

**0.597357988358**

```
<?php
$title='Title';
$content='Content//';

$start_b = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i<30000; ++$i): ?>
<div class='title'><?php echo $title; ?></div>
<div class='content'><?php echo $content; ?></div>
<?php endfor;
echo microtime(true) - $start_b;
?>
```

**2.21032595634**

Comment: Неужели первый способ быстрее?

Comment: Попробуйте и убедитесь сами, я же не зря выложил код для теста?  
Хотя за корректность подобного тестирования ручаться не могу. Слишком мало опыта программирования.  

Лично для меня второй способ удобнее первого, за редким исключением.

Comment: Запустил у себя вышеприведённый код.
1 - вариант 0.00045490264892578
2 - вариант 0.0045950412750244

Хм. ВенЗель преклоняюсь. первый способ примерно в 10 раз быстрее.

Comment: @VenZell просто странно, ведь во втором способе php используется меньше, но echo используется 2 раза.

Но все равно это не может убить производительность в примерно 4 раза.

Comment: @M11, если хотите, подождите комментария или ответа от человека, у которого больше опыта. Может статься так, что данное сравнение в корне неверно. Я сам удивлен результатом.

Comment: Да, heredoc чуть быстрее, но разница просто мизерная. Не знаю, где проверял @VenZell, но запустил у себя на VDS и результат такой:

    // echo 
    0.033659934997559
    0.041728973388672
    0.03505802154541
    // heredoc
    0.027704000473022
    0.046306848526001
    0.032881021499634

Comment: А может дело в ?> и <?php а не в echo?

Answer (score 3):

используйте HEREDOC синтаксис как можно... ээ.. вообще не используйте. Второй способ - это правильный способ. Если хотите узнать скорость работы скрипта, то можно сделать [так](http://shublog.ru/php/kak-uznat-vremya-vypolneniya-skripta-na-php/)

Comment: Но ведь есть много факторов. Вот например в втором способе вызывается 2 раза, а в первом один.

Comment: Первый способ - это яркий пример легкого говнокода. 

Посмотрите как устроена CMS Opencart. Там шаблоны построены как у вас во втором способе. Первый способ неудобный и если вы захотите посмотреть на подсветку вашего кода, то внутри HEREDOC вы кроме одного сплошного цвета ничего не увидите. Советую вам не использовать его вообще. Возможно его кто-то и использует, но я даже не понимаю зачем.

Comment: Во втором случае html код отдаётся сразу на обработку клиенту(браузеру), делая небольшие остановки для вставки в html код переменных php. В первом же случае, сначала php код со всем html кодом обрабатывается на сервере. А это не только время, а ещё и ресурсы сервера. К тому же если в echo вставлять много html кода, его читабельность и скорость редактирования существенно понизятся, знаю по своему опыту.

Comment: @mountpoint HEREDOC был использован случайно не для того что именно о нем говорить можно и так echo("");

Comment: @mountpoint, про подсветку - чушь. Пример из PHPStorm:  

![Подсветка в PHPStorm][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/hTxlSMJ.png

Comment: @VenZell, PHPStorm не пользовался. Извиняюсь за неверную инфу

Answer (score 2):

Лучше так ;)

```
<div class='title'><?= $title ?></div>
<div class='content'><?= $content ?></div>
```

Comment: не лучше =) short tags могут быть отключены и зачем дополнительные проблемы при переносе сайта?) вот так лучше всего <div class='title'><?php echo $title; ?></div>

Comment: Интересный способ, о таком и не знал. А у Вас есть о нем какая то информация?

Comment: Директива php.ini
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag
short_open_tag boolean
Определяет, разрешается ли короткая форма записи (<? ?>) тегов PHP. Если вы хотите использовать PHP совместно с XML, вы можете отключить эту опцию, чтобы беспрепятственно использовать <?xml ?>. В противном случае, вы можете отобразить это при помощи PHP, например: <?php echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>'; ?>. Если же эта опция отключена, вы должны использовать длинную форму открывающего тега PHP (<?php ?>).

Comment: Погодьте-ка. По-моему, господа @mountpoint и @terantul путают <? ?> и <?= ?>. Читаем [мануал](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag): Директива short_open_tag также влияла на сокращение <?= до версии PHP 5.4.0, которое идентично записи <? echo. Начиная с версии PHP 5.4.0 запись <?= стала доступна всегда. Так что пользуйтесь без опасений.

Comment: я заберу свои слова обратно, когда хотябы 90% хостеров по умолчанию поставят PHP 5.4.0

Comment: @mountpoint, ну да. Это великая проблема поменять в настройках хостинга версию PHP.

Comment: Не поверите - великая. Проще хостера сменить.

Comment: @Denis Khvorostin, не все панели управления хостингов имеют такую возможность

Comment: @mountpoint short_open_tag стала в основных дистрибутивах по умолчанию false, как раз с php 5.4, думаю это даже как-то связано. ну и хостеры на shared обычно делают её true.

Comment: Человек узнал что-то новое, а значит, мой пост выполнил свою маленькую роль ;)
Минусующие - пусть минусуют.
А вот за поддержку - Спасибо ))

Answer (score 1):

всегда пишу так, работает на всех хостингах с php 5.3 в независимости включены ли шорт теги

```
<div class='title'><?= $title ?></div>
<div class='content'><?= $content ?></div>
```

Comment: @Валентин Жуков, ваш ответ дублирует ответ пользователя @Stan.

Comment: У меня нет возможности комментировать, он все правильно написал, хотел лишь добавить что это никакие не шорт теги

Comment: просто у меня пукан пипец как рвет, понаделают всякого говногода со своими шаблонизаторами, еще и пишут смарти это круто а этот код отвалится, нехрена не отвалится пропробывали бы сначала прежде чем писать всякую чушь

Answer (score -1):

Если нужно настолько сильно оптимизировать, то лучше оптимизировать не код, а инфраструктуру. Варианты:

- Написать не на PHP, а на Go/Java/C
- Более оптимально настроить php-fpm, nginx, ... (буферизирование вывода, gzip, ...)
- Использовать более быстрый сервер или несколько серверов с load balancer
- Кешировать страницы целиком или хотя бы блоки - [Кеширование с Varnish + ESI (RuHighload.com)](http://ruhighload.com/index.php/2010/01/22/%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%B2-100/)