# Некорректная работа цикла

Tags: php, while

Подскажите, нужно чтобы выводился циклически блок auto-select и все что в форме. На данном наброске случается беда, блоки корректно выводятся, а вот select - нет (в каждом последующем блоке прибавляется по одной данной, а не сразу все и во всех как должно быть). Если убрать echo из цикла, то выводится корректно select  и всего лишь одни блок, но не доходит информация из

```
 <div class="auto-name">'.$row["name"].'</div>
 <div class="auto-image"><img src="'.$row["image"].'"></div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста. Не знаю что уже делать

```
<?php 
include("db_connect.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM title");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $yearOptions .= '<option>'.$row["year"].'</option>';
    $typeOptions .= '<option>'.$row["type"].'</option>';
    $engineOptions .= '<option>'.$row["engine"].'</option>';

    echo '
    <div class="auto-select">
    <div class="auto-name">'.$row["name"].'</div>
    <div class="auto-image"><img src="'.$row["image"].'"></div>
    <div class="options">
        <form id="options" action="../blocks/podbor.php" method="POST">
            <select class="option-year option" name="year">'.$yearOptions.'</select> 
            <select class="option-class option" name="type">'.$typeOptions.'</select>
            <select class="option-type option" name="engine">'.$engineOptions.'</select>
            <input type="submit"class="option option-button" ></div>
        </form>
    </div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Для начала: у вас не соблюдается структура html — div следует закрыть после закрывающего тега формы. Касательно формирования вариантов выбора для формы: если для каждой записи требуется вывести все возможные ранее использованные варианты значений полей, то придётся пройти по массиву из БД дважды — первый раз собрать все возможные варианты выбора и сформировать код формы, второй — расставить код формы рядом с каждой записью.

Comment: А как такое реализовать хотя бы пример кода ,а то голова лопается уже от этого всего,предполагаю что так же можно как то сделать форму невидимой для цикла 1(а в самой форме будет другой цикл2).либо как то что бы оно собрало данные сначала а потом вывело ,что тоже не представляю как выполнить

Answer (score 1):

Код какой-то странный. Зачем использовать echo ? если можно сделать все проще.

```
<?php 

include("db_connect.php");

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM title");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

 <div class="auto-select">
          <div class="auto-name">'.$row["name"].'</div>
         <div class="auto-image"><img src="'.$row["image"].'"></div>
         <div class="options">
         <form id="options" action="../blocks/podbor.php" method="POST">
     <select class="option-year option" name="year">'.$yearOptions.'</select> 
     <select class="option-class option" name="type">'.$typeOptions.'</select>
     <select class="option-type option" name="engine">'.$engineOptions.'</select>
         <input type="submit"class="option option-button" ></div>
         </form>
         </div>
<? } // while end ?>
```

Попробуйте так.

Comment: $yearOptions и компанию определить забыли?

Comment: Это да, забыл. Основная мысль автору дана.

Comment: @Dimcheg, мне лично нравится вот этот вопрос и ответы на него:http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/286771/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-echo-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82

Comment: @Dimcheg Это, да. Только автор про другое спрашивает %)

Answer (score 1):

Ниже приведён базовый код с комментариями. Предполагается PHP 5.4+
Давно не брал в руки PHP, поэтому конструктивная критика приветствуется, возможно где-нибудь упущена точка с запятой.

```
function get_data($db_connection, $sql) {
    /**
     * Задача этой функции - получить данные из БД,
     * а также сгруппировать их для последующего использования
     * в select элементах формы.
     */

    // Здесь мы сохраним всю выборку для последующего
    // прохода по ней.
    $rows = [];

    // Здесь будут хранится возможные значения для select-элементов.
    $options = ['year'=>[], 'type'=>[], 'engine'=>[]];

    foreach ($db_connection->query($sql) as $row) {
        foreach ($options as $key=>&$choices) {
            array_push($choices, $row[$key]);
        }
        array_push($rows, $row);
    }

    // Вернуть несколько значений из функции можно 
    // при помощи массива:
    return [$rows, $options];
}

function render_data($data) {
    /**
     * Задача данной функции - отрисовать html,
     * наполнив данными, полученными ранее.
     */

    // Распаковать массив в локальные переменные позволяет list().
    list($rows, $options) = $data;

    // Далее с префиксами $tpl_ пойдут строки шаблонов.
    // Эти строки содержат маркеры вида {{ что-то }} для
    // вставки на эти места реальных данных.
    $tpl_row = '
    <!-- Это шаблон блока. Он формируется для каждого ряда из БД. 
         Другие шаблоны вкладываются в него по принципу матрёшки.
         Из кубиков собирается целое. -->
    <div class="auto-select">
        <div class="auto-name">{{ name }}</div>
        <div class="auto-image"><img src="{{ image }}"></div>
        <div class="options">{{ form }}</div>
    </div>';

    $tpl_form = '
    <!-- Это шаблон формы. Он тоже формируется для каждого ряда из БД. -->
    <form id="options" action="../blocks/podbor.php" method="POST">
        {{ selects }}
        <input type="submit" class="option option-button" >
    </form>';

    $tpl_select = '
    <!-- Это шаблон select элемента формы. 
         Он формируется для нескольких полей каждого ряда из БД. -->
    <select class="option-{{ key }} option" name="{{ key }}">
        {{ options }}
    </select>';

    // Далее с префиксом $func_ идут небольшие вспомогательные
    // анонимные функции, замыкания. 
    // Мы присваиваем эти функции переменным для обращения
    // к ним в дальнейшем.
    $func_replace = function($tpl, $from, $to) {
        // Эта функция заменяет маркеры в строке шаблона на значения.
        return str_replace("{{ {$from} }}", $to, $tpl);
    };

    // В определении этой анонимной функции указаны символы 
    // внешнего пространства имён при помощи use, чтобы она
    // могла к ним обращаться.
    $func_make_select = function($row, $key, $choices) 
                        use ($func_replace, $tpl_select) {
        // Эта функция формирует select элемент формы.
        // При этом делает в нём выбранным текущее значение из БД.
        $select_html = $func_replace($tpl_select, 'key', $key);
        $options_html = '';

        foreach ($choices as $choice) {
            $selected = ($row[$key] == $choice ? 'selected' : '');
            $options_html .= "<option {$selected}>{$choice}</option>";
        }

        return $func_replace($select_html, 'options', $options_html);
    };

    // Ниже следует код наполнения шаблона данными.
    $html = '';
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $row_html = $tpl_row;

        // Этот цикл заполняет неизменяемые поля name, image.
        foreach ($row as $key=>$value) {
            $row_html = $func_replace($row_html, $key, $value);
        }

        $selects_html = '';
        // Этот цикл собирает код всех select элементов.
        foreach ($options as $option_key=>$choices) {
            $selects_html .= $func_make_select($row, $option_key, $choices);
        }
        // Подставляем полученные выше HTML куски в шаблон.
        $form_html = $func_replace($tpl_form, 'selects', $selects_html);
        $row_html = $func_replace($row_html, 'form', $form_html);

        $html .= $row_html;

    }

    // Отправляет финальный HTML на вывод.
    echo $html;
}

// Вызвать функции выше можно таким способом.
render_data(get_data($db_connection, 'SELECT * FROM title'))
```

Обратите внимание, что у нас в функции *render_data()* получился мини-шаблонизатор.

Разумеется, если вы уже используете какой-то, то эта куча кода вам не нужна: достаточно будет создать шаблон — мы определяли его части в переменных с префиксом $tpl_ — и инструктировать ваш шаблонизатор передать в него имеющиеся у вас данные.

Если тема шаблонизаторов вас заинтересовала, можете обратиться к моей старой статье «[Шаблоны в шаблонизаторе и как шаблоны Django до PHP дошли (в очередной раз)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/170327/)»